# Variation of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

It is given that inner product $$ \left\langle a(t),b(t)\right\rangle =0,\quad \forall t\in[0,T] $$
where $a(t), b(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

If $\dot{a}(t)$ is known, is there a way to find an expression for $\dot{b}(t)$ ? If it helps $\dot{a}(t)=-Aa(t)$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

So far I got only this $$ \left\langle a(t),\dot{b}(t)\right\rangle +\left\langle \dot{a}(t),b(t)\right\rangle =0 $$

Comment: Not without constraints. Note that if $b$ satisfies the condition above, so does $-b$.

Comment: That is true. I only want to know some conditions on time evolution of $b(t)$. Even if there are family of curves that is fine.

I solved a bit more 
$$
\left\langle a(t),\dot{b}(t)\right\rangle +\left\langle -Aa(t),b(t)\right\rangle  =  0$$
$$\left\langle a(t),\dot{b}(t)\right\rangle +\left\langle a(t),-adj(A)b(t)\right\rangle   =  0$$
$$\left\langle a(t),\dot{b}(t)-adj(A)b(t)\right\rangle   =  0
 $$

Comment: Even here I am unable to rule out that $\dot{b}(t)-adj(A)b(t)$ is always orthogonal to $a(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left\langle a(t),v\right\rangle = 0$ define hyperplanes through the origin. Depending on the matrix $A$ it may rotate or not, take for example $A=I$.

Alternatively, think of $a(t)$ as tangents along a curve $\gamma(t)$, $\dot\gamma(t)=a(t)$, then $b(t)$ is the moving normal to the curve. In any case finding $b(t)$ would indeed require some more information.

Comment: Even with $n=2$ don't you need more information? Nothing constrains the magnitude of $b$ or that it stays on the same side of the curve.